# Executar um script uma vez sim e outra não

Tags: php, javascript, lógica

estou com uma dificuldade em criar uma lógica e/ou código.

Eu tenho uma landing page que preciso de uma forma simples, de preferência sem usar banco de dados, executar um script uma vez sim e outra não.

Por exemplo:

- Usuário 1 se cadastra: executaScript()
- Usuário 2 se cadastra: *não executa o script*
- Usuário 3 se cadastra: executaScript()
- Usuário 4 se cadastra: *não executa o script*
- Usuário 5 se cadastra: executaScript()
- Usuário 6 se cadastra: *não executa o script*
- Usuário 7 se cadastra: executaScript()
- Usuário 8 se cadastra: *não executa o script*

...

Até acredito que possa ser feito usando um simples banco de dados para controlar com true ou false, mas estou esbarrando a algum tempo na lógica. Alguém pode ajudar?

Pode ser feito em PHP ou Vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Os usuário são cadastrados onde? Eles possuem algum número único e sequencial de identificação, basta fazer:

```
if($id_do_ususario % 2 === 0){
    executaScript();
}
```

Dessa forma quando o `id` for 1 ele não irá acionar, quando for 2 irá, quando for 3 não irá executar o comando... Só irá executar o comando em números divisíveis por 2.

Comment: Pensei na mesma solução.

Comment: Os usuários são cadastrados em um banco de dados, mas durante esse cadastro é disparado um pixel para contar conversão na campanha. Então esse pixel precisa ser disparado uma vez sim e outra não, independente de quem esteja cadastrando ou quando.

Comment: Então, se existir uma chave primária em auto-increment, você pode usar o `mysqli_insert_id()`, este será o id do usuário. Isso não vai funcionar se você usa Transaction do MySQL, porque pode ter lacunas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
não entendo muito de PHP, mas para o que você quer acho que uma solução simples +- assim:

```
$file = fopen("verifica.txt", 'r');
$ler = fgets($file, 1024);

if($ler > 0){
    fwrite($file, "1"); //Grava "1" no arquivo para saber que foi executada a função
    executaScript();
} else {
    fwrite($file, "0"); //Grava "0" no arquivo para saber que NÃO foi executada a função
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Obrigado @Daniel pela ajuda, tive que modificar um pouco o código para funcionar mas a sua lógica está correta.

Answer (score 0):

Solução para a questão:

```
$ler = file_get_contents("verifica.txt");

if($ler == "0"){
    file_put_contents("verifica.txt","1"); //Grava "1" no arquivo para saber que foi executada a função
    executaScript();
} else {
    file_put_contents("verifica.txt","0"); //Grava "0" no arquivo para saber que NÃO foi executada a função
}
```